# Kafka Consumer NoMethodError: undefined method `length' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, supervisord

I'm running multiple kafka consumers, each on their own server, that are reading from the same topic defined on a remote kafka cluster. Only 5 of 50 servers are successfully running the consumer process. The rest are failing to start - here are the logs:

> I, [2017-06-20T20:25:13.524287 #13302]  INFO -- : Registered for
>   conversions-processor as web1:d671ebce-bf76-4917-b504-ffd5924994f2 I,
>   [2017-06-20T20:25:13.529857 #13302]  INFO -- : 6 instances have been
>   registered: web11:86472d4d-cc95-4a5d-bc52-d1c97a8a9c34,
>   web1:d671ebce-bf76-4917-b504-ffd5924994f2,
>   web14:818a5194-bb51-48d4-bd59-2221a4d3c7ac,
>   web12:11e3f37e-5612-4306-bb1d-bf831da42052,
>   web13:8ace8116-09a4-451c-80b2-8b199ebf45be,
>   web10:8b17b591-9cb0-4193-a460-967ec30cc48c. bundler: failed to load
>   command:
>   /home/deploy/apps/test/current/exe/tracking-events-kafka-consumer.rb
>   (/home/deploy/apps/test/current/exe/tracking-events-kafka-consumer.rb)
>   NoMethodError: undefined method `length' for nil:NilClass
>
>   /home/deploy/apps/test/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/kafka-consumer-268309adaabe/lib/kafka/consumer.rb:130:in`
>   manage_partition_consumers'
>   /home/deploy/apps/test/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/kafka-consumer-268309adaabe/lib/kafka/consumer.rb:88:in
>   `block in each' I, [2017-06-20T20:25:15.320951 #13363]  INFO -- :
>   Registered for conversions-processor as
>   web1:15494044-ddf7-4702-9578-ab828be62478 I,
>   [2017-06-20T20:25:15.325198 #13363]  INFO -- : 6 instances have been
>   registered: web13:8ace8116-09a4-451c-80b2-8b199ebf45be,
>   web12:11e3f37e-5612-4306-bb1d-bf831da42052,
>   web10:8b17b591-9cb0-4193-a460-967ec30cc48c,
>   web11:86472d4d-cc95-4a5d-bc52-d1c97a8a9c34,
>   web14:818a5194-bb51-48d4-bd59-2221a4d3c7ac,
>   web1:15494044-ddf7-4702-9578-ab828be62478. bundler: failed to load
>   command:
>   /home/deploy/apps/test/current/exe/tracking-events-kafka-consumer.rb
>   (/home/deploy/apps/test/current/exe/tracking-events-kafka-consumer.rb)
>   NoMethodError: undefined method`length' for nil:NilClass
>   /home/deploy/apps/test/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/kafka-consumer-268309adaabe/lib/kafka/consumer.rb:130:in
>   `manage_partition_consumers'
>
>   /home/deploy/apps/test/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/kafka-consumer-268309adaabe/lib/kafka/consumer.rb:88:in`
>   block in each'

If I stop the consumer on one box - I can start it successfully on one of the boxes that had previously failed. It seems that my configuration only allows 5 consumers to be registered at a time?

My question is, why is this happening? and how might I fix it?

Any suggestions or insight, as always, is hugely appreciated!!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, all your consumers are in the same consumer-group and subscribe to the same topic wich have only 5 partitons. If you want distribute the consumation charge on 50 consumers you have to configure your topic with 50 partitions.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know, is there any benefit to increasing the number of partitions?

Comment: "More Partitions Lead to Higher Throughput" : https://www.confluent.io/blog/how-to-choose-the-number-of-topicspartitions-in-a-kafka-cluster/ ;)